# Is there a shortcut to insert {%%} in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to be able to just type lets say "%%" into my files and get "{%%}" to be typed out? How do I accomplish this in PyCharm?

Comment: Basically you want [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) First you need to create a template, set the abbreviation and the text you want to appear. After the template is defined just press `COMMAND/CTRL + J` wherever you want the template to be inserted. If the abbreviation was found, it will insert the template.