# Is there a shortcut for HTML blocks {%%} in PyCharm?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, pycharm

I am using HTML blocks like `{% block content %}` frequently but having to type out the brackets and percentage symbols is a hassle. Is there a shortcut or other way to automate this?

So far I just found this: [Is there a shortcut to insert {%%} in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609248/is-there-a-shortcut-to-insert-in-pycharm) with no good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-live-templates.html) for `{% code block %}`.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (or go to `Code` `>` `Insert Live Template`).
2. Start typing `block` (the name of the template) to filter the list.

   [image]
3. Press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click) after selecting the name from the list, and the template is inserted.

   [image]
4. You can find the `block` template at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Live Templates` `>` `Django` `>` `block`. (In case you want to [Configure the Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_configure)).

   [image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the thorough explanation. I wasn't able to find `django` in `live templates` but I was able to set up a `live template` for `html` that works just fine.